# Permanent Storage in Android after uninstallation of app

Tags: android

I am making an application in android. Now the issue which I am facing here is, I want to save one id, which should persist even after uninstallation of app. So is there any way which may fulfill my purpose, and also will be a better idea ? And if yes, Please tell me about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Place your id in external storage like sdcard in a text file. This will then persist even after uninstallation of application. But the downside is that it is prone to user deletion.